# How to search for an array of strings in a collection of log files

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have an array of names, and I want to find occurrences of those names in multiple log files. The code below works, but it only returns all the lines in the log where any of the names occur.

```
$array_of_names = 'name1','name2','etc'
$log_path = 'path_containing_log_files'
$logs = Get-ChildItem $log_path

foreach($log in $logs){
    Select-String -Path $file -Pattern $array_of_names
}
```

I want to get either a frequency table for the occurrences of the names in the log files, or just binary value per name that tells if the name ever occurred in any of the log files.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get either a frequency table for the occurrences of the names in the log files [...]

You can get that pretty easily:

1. Use the `-AllMatches` switches to make `Select-String` output *all matches* within a given line
2. Iterate over the `Matches` property on the resulting object to get the individually matched names
3. Use `Group-Object` to generate a frequency table

```
$array_of_names = 'name1','name2','etc'
$log_path = 'path_containing_log_files'
$logs = Get-ChildItem $log_path -File

# search all log files and extract the names of the log files where _any_ name was found
$results = $logs |Select-String -Pattern $array_of_names -AllMatches 
$matchingLogFiles = $results |ForEach-Object -MemberName Filename

# group matching substrings based on value
$frequencyTable = $results |ForEach-Object -MemberName Matches |Group-Object Value -AsHashtable

foreach($key in $frequencyTable.psbase.Keys){
    # turn the grouped output table into a frequency table by mapping each entry to its count
    $frequencyTable[$key] = $frequencyTable[$key].Count
}
```